# Как сохранить параметры в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Пытаюсь сохранить данные, но ничего не сохраняется.Что я делаю не так? API-26..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);
        SharedPreferences prefrences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APPNAME,this.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(prefrences.contains(APPNAME)) {
            txt1.setText(prefrences.getString("savedtext", ""));
        }

    }
    public void myClickForSave(View view){
        save(editText1.getText().toString());
    }
    public void save(String str) {
        SharedPreferences prefrences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APPNAME,getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefrences.edit();
        ed.clear();
        ed.putString("savedtext",str);
        ed.commit();
        ed.apply();
    }
```

Comment: а зачем вы используете commit() и apply() вместе?

Comment: Сначала комитить а потом применить.подумал как с гит баш.

Comment: попробуйте убрать ed.commit()

Comment: Не сработал.....

Comment: попробуйте убрать clear()

Comment: Опять не сработал

Comment: Манипулировал и с контекстами.все равно не в какую

Comment: И никаких ошибок?

Comment: commit() и apply() выполняют одно и то же действие, но apply() делает это в асинхронном потоке, его использовать предпочтительней. Оба метода вместе использовать нет никакого смысла.

Comment: Спасибо...... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замени это:

```
if(prefrences.contains(APPNAME)) {
  txt1.setText(prefrences.getString("savedtext", ""));
}
```

На это:

```
txt1.setText(prefrences.getString("savedtext", ""));
```

Функция **contains** `prefrences.contains(APPNAME)` ищет значение по ключу **APPNAME**. Ты записываешь его по ключу **savedtext**, он же и сохраняется. `prefrences.contains(APPNAME)` возвращает false и код `txt1.setText(prefrences.getString("savedtext", ""));` не выполняется, хотя значение сохранено.

Comment: Спасибо.заработало